# how to test cache using Powermockito

Tags: java, caching, mockito

I want to test my cache using mockito :

```
@Before
public void init() {
    cacheManager = PowerMockito.mock(CacheManager.class);
    cache = PowerMockito.mock(Cache.class);
}

@Test
public void test_Cache() throws Exception {

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(csvReaderService, "csvFile", csvFileOK);

    Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME);

    assertNotNull(cache);
    assertEquals(0, cache.getSize());

    csvReaderService.readCSV();

    cache = cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME);
    // In cache should be 1 record
    assertNotNull(cache);
    assertEquals(1, cache.getSize());
}
```

I get error in `assertNotNull(cache);` which mean that cache is null.
Should I init "cacheManager" somewhere before calling "cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME)" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the mock method:

```
when(cacheManager.getCache(any(String.class))).thenReturn(cache );
```